# Why did I get ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, python-import, pprint

I tried the following code to import pprint from pprint module like `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. But I got an error instead. Why did I get this error?

```
import pprint.pprint as p
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-029262df2bb9> in <module>
----> 1 import pprint.pprint as p

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pprint.pprint'; 'pprint' is not a package
```

Comment: `pyplot` is a **submodule** of `matplotlib`. Therefore you can use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. `pprint.pprint` is a method, and cannot be imported like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there's no module `pprint.pprint`, only a module `pprint`. You mean:

```
from pprint import pprint as p
```

*(From the **module** `pprint` import the **name** `pprint` as `p`.)*

Comment: Is there any command to know whether a particular method one is importing is a module or method on the lines of help(<method>)?

Comment: The big clue is that you’re *calling* `pprint()`, not access further attributes on it…